# Problem with video app with common black triangle

Tags: 22.04, gstreamer

I have big problem with common black triangle if I recorded from screen recorder then it shows a black triangle.

Why does it use black triangle in video files?

How do I remove black triangle?

I use ATI Radeon RX 480 8 GB VRAM and Ubuntu 22.04.

How do I remove it? I already installed H264 decorder, ffmpeg4, gstreamer and ubuntu-restriction-extra etc...

I already tried with rm -fr $HOME/.cache/gstreamer-1.0

What do I need to do to get successful screen recording?